# Print stacktrace without throwing exception

Tags: python, stack-trace

I have inherited a large Python project in which there are points whereI want to know how I got there. So I would like to see a stracetrace.

It seems that the traceback module can do that, but I need to throw an exception.
Is there a way to get a stacktrace without throwing an exception?

Comment: Run it through a debugger and add breakpoints where you want to inspect things.

Comment: It pretty much is. There are several such questions and the first few I found by search were not very informative. Had I found this one first, I would never have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

traceback is one option:

```
import traceback

traceback.print_stack()
```

Answer (score 3):

you want [inspect.stack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)(), which returns a list of frame objects

import inspect

```
def a(): 
   b()

def b():
   c()

def c():
   print inspect.stack()
```